# Calculate significant genes from significant level

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, genetics

If I know that in a study a total of 2936 associations reached a given statistical significance level (P < $6\times 10^{-11}$) and that the total number of SNPs analyzed that belonged to a specific gene were 642 764 (total entries were 941 320 and NaNs were 298 556).

How can I show how this value (2936) is calculated from the significant level and number of tested proteins?

Comment: The number of associations is not calculated from the $p$-value; if anything it is the other way round

Comment: @Henry That is the task I have been given